# How accurate is the idea of differentiable functions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Shown below is an image illustrating the derivative of the function $f$ with respect to both directions $x$ and $y$. So we want to find the derivative in the direction $[\delta x, \delta y]$ or the directional derivative. Why is the change in the function f in the direction $[\delta x, \delta y]$ dependent on the sum of its constituent changes in both directions $x$ and $y$?

[image]

Comment: I find it very inaccurate, just not to say downright wrong.

Comment: The conditions you've shown are the *definition* of differentiable. *If* those conditions are satisfied, then, by definition, the function is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$. Not every function is differentiable.